# Pressured air canisters as portable air conditioners?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, temperature

I fill up a bike tire with a CO2 canister, and it was cold as hell!

I am now wondering why don't companies manufacture pressured air canisters, with slow-release valves, so people in the Middle East and Africa can have some mercy? We could, at least in theory, keep 5 to 10 cans in a belt around our waist and wear our clothes on top of that. Then when the going gets tough, we can open up the valves and let the air expand using heat energy from our bodies?

If you tell me that the canisters are a safety hazard, then I ask is it still a hazard if the canister are thick-walled, such that it leaves no chance of strain induced explosions?

Pros, cons and mistakes in my understanding would help!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is generally called *air-cycle refrigeration*. The cooling effect of decompressing a flask of compressed air is not all that great; in practice it takes a lot of compressed air to derive a significant amount of cooling in this way. Airplanes use *bleed air* taken off the compressor stages of their engines to furnish air conditioning because there's lots of it available and the required machinery is light in weight, but in most other contexts it is uneconomical compared to *mechanical refrigeration* (heat pump technology using compressors working with freon-class working media).

Comment: I am not asking about efficiency here. All I care about is that if I pressurize air to 300 psi into a small 0.00001884955 m³ cylinder and release it under my clothes, it will cool me down. Every degree down counts when you're bombarded with 49°C ambient dry air...

Comment: It will help but also it will evaporate sweat from your skin which will be a great help in cooing you down- in fact, the evaporation effect may be stronger than the expansion effect. Together they work great, as long as you have plenty of compressed air on hand.

Comment: and how much would "plenty" be? If it's 49°C outside, and the compressed air is at 300 psi, what volume of air would I need to bring the inside temperature down by 10°C for 20 minutes (consider my clothes are an open system, and heat transfer takes place)?

Comment: Based on my experience, you would need 5 gallons at 100PSI.

Comment: But what about at 300 psi?

Comment: now you need a heavier tank with thicker walls, but you might get by with 2 gallons instead of 5 (the relationship is very nonlinear). suggest you ask this on the engineering stack exchange for a more practical answer.